# asp:literal printing in final markup from kentico

Tags: .net, asp.net, kentico

A third party developer is building a kentico site for us and there's an asp:Literal tag printing in the head element as delivered to the end user. The tag is the following,

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litTags" EnableViewState="false" />
```

Is this essential? It's causing the markup to fail validation and some browsers to complain. He says it's essential for templates, but I can't see any sign of one getting printed on Kentico's own site, or any of the showcase sites. I can see that the tag appears in kentico's templating documentation, so I'm assuming the tag just isn't getting parsed by the server correctly.

Not being a Kentico or ASP guy I can't offer him any advice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This markup shouldn't be delivered to the client. I think you may need a `runat="server"` attribute on the `<head>` element as well so ASP.Net will correctly see the Literal and output some text instead of the actual `<asp:Literal...` markup.